# JavaScript Table content Add and Delete

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a table content with JS. What I can update with a button or clear data from the table.

- Phone Number: phoneNumber.value
- Bay Number: bayNumber.Value (it's not added yet, but will work same)

The First column in the table is always the same (Phone Number and Bay Number), but the second column should change what is in the input after I press the save button (it works fine) Just if I press the delete, it deletes the all table.

I think the problem is how I created the table, but don't know how should I fix it.

```
//FORM//
var form = document.createElement('div');
form.style.width = "500px";
form.style.height = "500px";
form.style.margin = "auto";
form.style.textAlign = "center";
form.style.paddingTop = "20px";
form.style.background = "grey";
form.classList.add("printVisible");
document.body.appendChild(form);

var phoneNumber = document.createElement("INPUT");
phoneNumber.setAttribute("type", "text");
phoneNumber.value = "07";
phoneNumber.classList.add("hiddenPrint");
form.appendChild(phoneNumber);

var bayNumber = document.createElement("INPUT");
bayNumber.setAttribute("type", "text");
bayNumber.value = "Bay Number";
bayNumber.classList.add("hiddenPrint");
form.appendChild(bayNumber);

var buttonSave = document.createElement("BUTTON");
buttonSave.addEventListener("click", saveDatas);
var buttonSaveT = document.createTextNode("Save");
buttonSave.appendChild(buttonSaveT);
form.appendChild(buttonSave);

var buttonClear = document.createElement("BUTTON");
buttonClear.addEventListener("click", clearDatas);
var buttonClearT = document.createTextNode("Clear");
buttonClear.appendChild(buttonClearT);
form.appendChild(buttonClear);

var phoneNumberT = document.createElement("P");
form.appendChild(phoneNumberT);
var bayNumberT = document.createElement("P");
form.appendChild(bayNumberT);


//SAVE BUTTON//

function saveDatas() {
   tablePhoneNumberTx.textContent = phoneNumber.value;
   bayNumberT.textContent = bayNumber.value;
}

//CLEAR BUTTON//

function clearDatas() {
   tablePhoneNumberTx.textContent = "";
   bayNumberT.textContent = "";
}

//TABLE//

    let body = document.body;
    let tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.style.textAlign = "center";
    tbl.style.margin = "auto";

    let tablePhoneNumberTx = tbl.insertRow();
    let tablePhoneNumber = tablePhoneNumberTx.insertCell();
    tablePhoneNumber.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Phone Number`));
    tablePhoneNumberTx.appendChild(document.createTextNode(phoneNumber.value));
    tablePhoneNumber.style.border = "1px solid black";
    tablePhoneNumber.style.width = "250px";
    tablePhoneNumberTx.style.border = "1px solid black";
    tablePhoneNumberTx.style.background = "250px";


    form.appendChild(tbl);
```

P.S. Its a TamperMonkey Script so, must be everything in JS

Comment: even if everything must be written only in javascript, it does not prohibit you to factorize your code.

Comment: I'm not programmer, just doing for fun. Could you explain me what wrong with this code? :)

Comment: too much code here, like some sort of forest hiding your problem. read the recommendations of this site to properly ask a question, and for which your interlocutors will want to answer without having to clear everything. There are nearly 3 million JS questions here, about 1 every 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

some sort of code factorization you could use, but since you wrote "only JS" I wonder why you are referencing CSS classes?

```js
const newEl = ( tag, styling={}, attrbs={} ) =>
  {
  let elm = document.createElement(tag)
  for(let key in styling) elm.style[key]  = styling[key]
  for(let key in attrbs)  elm[key]        = attrbs[key]
  return elm
  };

let myDiv = document.body
  .appendChild
    ( newEl('div'
      , {width:'200px', margin:'auto'}
      , {className:'toto', textContent:'hello world'}
    ) ); 

console.log( myDiv )
```

Comment: Because this is how I can do styling. The first part of your code I don't really unterstand

Comment: @DaniMisi this is just a `named function` in [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)